# libusb_interrupt_transfer ends with LIBUSB_ERROR_IO

Tags: c++, stm32, libusb, libusb-1.0, lsusb

Writting to the device with libusb_interrupt_transfer(...), ends with LIBUSB_ERROR_IO all the time. 
Libusb version: libusb-1.0.4
STM32F103 code - st example for hid devices

Checked:

1. Endpoint in code is set to as in lsusb : 0x81
2. in usbmon I can see requests for descriptor etc. but when I trigger libusb_interrupt_transfer(...) there is no communication ( no log in usbmon )
3. STM32 board never gets into specified interrupt endpoint
4. Device handle used is proper

What would be next steps to track down the problem?

Here is lsusb output:

`Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0483:5750 STMicroelectronics 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0483 STMicroelectronics
  idProduct          0x5750 
  bcdDevice            2.00
  iManufacturer           1 STMicroelectronics
  iProduct                2 STM32 Custm HID
  iSerial                 3 8D8316685052
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           41
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 None
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.10
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength     163
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0002  1x 2 bytes
        bInterval              32
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0002  1x 2 bytes
        bInterval              32
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered`

Comment: show use your code. nothing can be understood just from device descriptor and a few words about the problem.

Comment: confirm that you have set-interface (and control over the interface) before using the endpoint.